# On whom do Jedi practice mind tricks?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, jedi-training

We are shown in the original Star Wars trilogy (and even in the prequels...) that Jedi generally require years of focused training to develop mastery of their Force abilities. Notwithstanding certain characters in the most recent film, we can assume that the mind trick is likewise a power that must be developed through training. Since (Qui-Gon), Obi-Wan, and Luke all utilize the mind-trick at least once, we can assume it was a relatively common skill.

Since it would seem to violate the Jedi code of ethics to grab a random person and practice mind-tricks on them, who do Jedi-in-training practice the mind-trick technique on? My first thought was that they would practice on their teacher, but that sounds like trying to learn lightsaber swordsmanship by hitting an AT-AT with a stick.

Comment: If TFA is to be believed, it's not that hard. Plus Luke used it and he had no one to learn it from either, except having seen Ben do it.

Comment: Those aren't good examples. Luke and Rey are both particularly strong in the Force. For someone like Ahsoka, it takes practice. She had been shown to be imperfect in her usage of the technique.

Comment: I offer the scenario where "subject to Jedi Mind Trick practice" was one form of sentencing that can be passed on common criminals in the courts of the Republic, where Padawans will practice getting convicts to rethink their lives. Successful rehabilitations will be released and hired as Temple staff.

Comment: When I take rebels into account it looks like the FIRST target are animals. They learn to control it and prior to that Ezra never used anything mind trick wise and controlling animals seems to be going into the same direction. Afterwards it isnt shown how he trains that ability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any reason to assume that young Jedi don't learn the "mind-trick" in exactly the same way that they learn to control their other Force senses, **as Padawan learners to more senior Jedi.**

This cooperative arrangement is likely to bring them into contact with all sorts of scoundrels, criminals and ne'er-do-wells who need their minds tricking, and when the opportunity presents itself, the young Jedi would presumably be encouraged to use their fledgling powers.

The more senior Jedi would then stand ready to step in, in case it doesn't work the first time.